# How do I get a number in a link out of HTML code with preg_match?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need to find out, whether in an array there is a specific HTML code. The array contains HTML codes and I need to get a number, that is included in a link.
This would be what I am searching for (the number 10 ist the number I want):
class = "active" href = "http://www.example.com/something-10

So I tried the following using preg_match:

```
if(preg_match('/class = "active" href = "http://www.example.com/something-(.*)/',$array["crawler"],$arr)) { print_r($arr,true); }
```

Unfortunately this will give me nothing as result. So I guess, something is wrong with my preg_match. I allready checked all the manuals, but I still dont get what I am doing wrong.

Could someone help me with this? Thank you!

phpheini

Answer (score 2):

Aside from advising you to [not parse HTML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662), your particular regular expression needs different delimiters:

```
preg_match('~class = "active" href = "http://www\.example\.com/something-(\d+)~', ...)
```

Alternatively, you could have escaped the slashes within the regex, but that leads to LSS (leaning slash syndrome):

```
preg_match('/class = "active" href = "http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/something-(.*)/', ...)
```

And that's just ugly.

You should have gotten an error, if your `error_reporting` is turned on.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that now everything after the number will be shown, I only need the number. So, now output is: 50.htm"></div><a href= and so on. How can I tell the expression to cut off after the 50?

Comment: @phpheini Updated the answer; changed `.*` to `\d+` (`\d+` means "one digit or more").